# Extracting numbers out of a string using several separators in R

Tags: r, string, data.table, substring

I have many output files with this data structure:  median (low, high), I want to separate all of the numbers into their own columns but I am having difficulty because of the parentheses and the comma-separated numbers within the parentheses.

```
library(data.table)

# Data structure = median (low, high)
output <- c("9540000 (0,11140000)", 
            "8.81329 (0,8.81329)", 
            "27080000 (0,45290000)", 
            "23.4947 (0,63.2807)") 

desired_out <- data.table(median = c(9540000, 8.81329, 27080000, 23.4947),
                          low = c(0, 0, 0, 0),
                          high = c(11140000, 8.81329, 45290000, 63.2807))
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
out <- tstrsplit(gsub("\\(|\\)", "", output), " |,")
setnames(setDT(out), c("median", "low", "high"))

out          

     median low     high
1:  9540000   0 11140000
2:  8.81329   0  8.81329
3: 27080000   0 45290000
4:  23.4947   0  63.2807
```

Comment: Whenever I try to make the columns numeric with `as.numeric()`, I get a strange result and the output file thinks the row is the original tstrsplit vector. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Solution using `data.table`:

Create original data:

```
output <- c("9540000 (0,11140000)", 
            "8.81329 (0,8.81329)", 
            "27080000 (0,45290000)", 
            "23.4947 (0,63.2807)") 

library(data.table)
df <- data.table(output)
```

Separate string variable into median, low and high using data.table's `tstrsplit` (we use base `gsub` to get rid of the parentheses):

```
df[, c("median", "low", "high") := tstrsplit(gsub("[()]", "", output), "[ ,]")]
```

df is now:

> ```
>                   output   median low     high
> 1:  9540000 (0,11140000)  9540000   0 11140000
> 2:   8.81329 (0,8.81329)  8.81329   0  8.81329
> 3: 27080000 (0,45290000) 27080000   0 45290000
> 4:   23.4947 (0,63.2807)  23.4947   0  63.2807
> ```